# Entry List template

Tags: templating, entries

I have a problem - I can not properly conclude the list of entries.

Total output last 3 records. Each entry must be a separate template. How can this be implemented?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following... you want to output the last 3 entries by date created regardless of the section?

Comment: no. sorry for bad english, i use google translate :)

1 channel, name - news. output 3 last entries. should be like this - http://imgur.com/fZtjfhl

Answer (score 2):

If I'm following you correctly, I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').limit(3).find() %}

<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li>{{entry.postDate }} - {{ entry.title }}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

By default, Craft will order results by the date created in descending order, so that query will get you the last 3 entries in the news section and display them.

Comment: No. Sorry for bad english. I found solution - {{ cycle(['style1', 'alt style2', 'style3', ], loop.index0)|raw }}